# In table tennis what is the largest ITTF tournament event of the year?

Tags: table-tennis, tournaments, ittf

Just started watching more table tennis with the use of ITTV. In sports, there are many competitions that muster the best athletes in the world: world series, superbowl, the olympics, tour de france, PGA Masters, etc.

In table tennis, what is the largest ITTF event that is the equivalent to a superbowl, etc?

Comment: According to my opinion, it is the World Championship.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 very large tournaments. One being the [Table Tennis World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_Tennis_World_Cup). This tournament happens one time a year. Though, this is only a singles championship. Doubles events do not exist.

On the other hand another very large event is the [World Table Tennis Championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Table_Tennis_Championships). The difference is that this event runs annually switching between doubles and singles every year.

You do still have Open events that are large, though these are some of the largest annual events.

Hope this helps!